# Postgres Replication with no configuration access

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I am currently working with a [Managed Instance from TimescaleDB](https://docs.timescale.com/mst/latest/#managed-service-for-timescaledb) and have incoming data. Now, I am setting up another instance, but this time it will be self-hosted and managed by me.

As such, I would like to setup some sort of replication so that the data coming into the managed instance is accessible in the self-hosted one (after a while, does not have to be live). I've looked into setting up [replication with WAL streaming](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/replication-and-ha/configure-replication/#configure-the-primary-database), however I've run into an issue.

Most replication workflows require changes in `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` files which I cannot access (Managed instance). TimescaleDB support also says modifying this is not possible.

Is there a way to achieve this, without access to those files?

Comment: Voting to close this question, because this is a support question to TimescaleDB commercial product, as open source developers cannot know how TimescaleDB internally manages their products and what is possible or not possible.